# Cohomology of a blow-up of a real algebraic variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, real-algebraic-geometry, blow-ups

Let $X$ be a complex algebraic variety, $Z \subset X$ a closed subvariety, $\mathrm{Bl}_Z X$ the blow-up and $E$ the exceptional divisor. There is an isomorphism of cohomology groups
$$ H^k(X(\mathbf C),\mathbf Z) \oplus H^k(E(\mathbf C),\mathbf Z) \cong H^k(\mathrm{Bl}_Z X(\mathbf C),\mathbf Z) \oplus H^k(Z(\mathbf C),\mathbf Z)$$
for all $k$. This comes about because the complex $Rf_\ast\mathbf Z$ is the direct sum of its cohomology sheaves, where $f \colon \mathrm{Bl}_Z X \to X$ is the blow-up. So it is very easy to compute the cohomology groups of a blow-up in complex algebraic geometry.

Now suppose instead $X$ is a real algebraic variety and $Z$ is a real subvariety. There is no such simple formula for the cohomology of the set of real points $\mathrm{Bl}_Z(\mathbf R)$. For example, if $X = \mathbf P^1 \times \mathbf P^1$ and $Z$ is a (real) point, then $X(\mathbf R)$ is a torus and $\mathrm{Bl}_Z X(\mathbf R)$ is a Klein bottle. So in this case the Leray spectral sequence for $\mathrm{Bl}_Z X(\mathbf R) \to X(\mathbf R)$ does not degenerate, even rationally.

Is there a systematic account somewhere of what one can say in the real case? For example, does the situation simplify with $\mathbf Z/2$-coefficients? Or rationally? Can one describe the differentials in the Leray spectral sequence in terms of things like Gysin maps or Stiefel-Whitney classes?